# Decoradores en class-based views

Tags: python, django

Tengo un error al utilizar el decorador `@login_required` en una vista basada en clase, pero esta funciona bien en una vista basada en funciones:

*Views.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from .forms import ElementForm
from .models import Element

@login_required()
class Home(ListView):
    model = Element

class ElementDetail(DetailView):
    model = Element

@login_required()
def new_element(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ElementForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            element = form.save()
            element.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = ElementForm()
    template = loader.get_template('new_element.html')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

*Urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^elements$', views.Home.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ElementDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^element/new$', views.new_element, name='new_element'),
]
```

Al dejar el `@login_required` solo en la funcion, el codigo corre sin problemas, pero al agregarlo a la clase class Home, me arroja el siguiente error en consola:

```
File "/home/didier/Documents/Projects/inventory/inv/elements/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    url(r'^elements$', views.Home.as_view(), name='home'),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para decorar una CBV, tienes que usar el decorador `method_decorator`, ya lo habías importado, solo tienes que usarlo:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import ListView


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class Home(ListView):
    model = Element
```

Lo que hace `method_decorator` es decorar un método de la clase específica y para decorar una CBV tienes que hacerlo en el método `dispatch` de la clase.

Lo anterior es equivalente a esto:

```
class Home(ListView):
    model = Element

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Home, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

La otra opción es usar el decorador en tu `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^elements$', login_required(views.Home.as_view()), name='home'),
    # ...
]
```

### Actualización

A partir de Django 1.9 es posible usar [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó perfectamente

Answer (score 1):

Adicionalmente puedes usar un `LoginRequiredMixin` a tus vistas, te recomiendo usar [axes](https://github.com/django-pci/django-axes).

Comment: Me parece que la versión 1.9 ya viene con ese Mixin